# Drupal Views filtering by taxonomy term

Tags: drupal, view

I have content type that has mandatory term reference field to four terms:

```
A
B
C
D
```

I need to create query (list) which gives me back only the last 4 node associeated to each term.

Basicly I want to run these queries in my view:

```
SELECT myfield FROM mytable WHERE term_field='A' LIMIT 1;
SELECT myfield FROM mytable WHERE term_field='B' LIMIT 1;
SELECT myfield FROM mytable WHERE term_field='C' LIMIT 1;
SELECT myfield FROM mytable WHERE term_field='D' LIMIT 1;
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You can do this through the Views UI. Any reason you're doing it through manual SQL queries?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I actually want to do it in views UI but I can't figure out how. I can add only one filter criteria: Content: Has taxonomy term=A. But how can I add for B, C and D terms in the same view?
I need only last node from all terms.

Comment: So you want a view that shows four articles, the last one tagged with A, the last one tagged with B, the las one tagged with C, and the last one tagged with D, correct? Just to make sure I understand you correctly before posting a solution.

Comment: Exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this through the Views UI and Views attachments. First, create a view page (or block) with the criteria for taxonomy term A.
[image: Filter criteria for the first view]

Then, create an attachment for each of your taxonomy terms you want after that. **Note: Make sure to do them in order. B, then C, then D.**

[image: Views add attachment]

On the attachments, create the view as if you would any other page or block, except with the filter criteria changed to what you want. (Note: make sure when changing the filter criteria to set it to "This attachment (override)".)

[image: Filter criteria for second view]

In the attachment section, put "Attach to: Page" and "Attachment position: After" (or whatever you called your first view, in this example I renamed it to "A").

[image: Attachment settings]

This should give you the result you are looking for. (There aren't any articles showing up because I don't have any tagged with those taxonomy terms, but you can see the title of the page view and each attachment.)

[image: Final result]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and effort to help. Description was so nicely done! Very easy to understand and follow. That was it. Learned what attachment is for. Thanks again!